# How to draw outline around a borderless form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, gdi

I have a form that I am using as a splash screen. Since it is a splash it does not have a border on it. The splash screen is white so when it loads against something else that is white it looks funy. I was thinking of adding an outline around the form about 1 px or so to give it a thin border. Think of it as adding a stroke to an image in photoshop. How would I do this? I am using vb.net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use GDI+:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)

    Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.ClientSize.Width - 1, Me.ClientSize.Height - 1)

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
End Sub
```

(You can substitute any `Pen` for `Pens.Black`, of course.)

Comment: Works perfectly. I really Appreciate it.

Comment: Weird the only thing I see wrong is that even though the background of the form is set to white it will draw the background to whatever color is behind it. Also the splash screen does not close automatically when main form is loaded like it should. Which isn't a problem because I can close it manually on on the form_load of the main form.. Im just wondering why this happens?

Comment: @user1632018: You're sure it didn't act like that before overriding `OnPaintBackground`? (In regards to the closing, I mean.) As for drawing whatever colour is behind it, that's my mistake; see edit.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Works great. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the following:

```
    Private Sub frm_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, Me.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset)
    End Sub
```

Color and ButtonBorderStyle can both be customized to what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, this simple line of code is working perfectly!

Comment: This is actually better

Answer (score 0):

If you use docked panels in the form, this border might now show. I suggest providing a 'Padding' of 1 on all edge of the form if you use docked panel in your form. This works perfectly.